# Groovy .reverseEach vs Stack

Tags: groovy, stack

I'm making a simple script that gets some data, puts it in some form of collection, then process it backwards. reverseEach on an ArrayList and a Stack implementation could surely do the job the same way. I would like to ask if there is some form of difference under the hood between the two, is there a benefit to the other in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Both `ArrayList` and `Stack` extend `AbstractList` so there is a lot of overlap in their APIs and internal implementation. One difference between them, is that `Stack` provides methods such as `pop()` and `push()` that allow it to treated as a last-in-first-out (LIFO) queue.